# Different behaviour on setting the src of an <img> and a <script>

Tags: javascript, dom, script-tag

If you set the `src` property of a branch new `img` element (or *Image* object) the browser fetches that image for you and the onload event is triggered at some point. This however does not seem to work for `script` elements. The script is not loaded until it's attached to the document which also triggers the script's execution. I can't find documentation on this behaviour and I'm wondering if it's a standard thing or not. I'm also wondering is there's any way to convince the `script` to behave like `img`.

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js';
script.onload = function () { console.log('script loaded'); }


var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg';
img.onload = function () { console.log('image loaded'); }
```

Only *image loaded* prints in the console.

Comment: Is the difference bugging you? Or is there something specific you are trying to do but struggling with? As for the current behavior I'm not sure if it is documented but it is the known behavior.

Comment: One main reason is that the execution can't happen until appended to the DOM as it may depend on DOM references. In addition there may be calls to date/time that are sensitive to when it is inserted that would be off if pre fetched and executed.

Comment: @scunliffe: Though of course, prefetching may be separate from executing (as it is from displaying, in the case of the image).

Comment: @Bergi true I suppose it could be downloaded and not executed (yet).  I'm not sure if setting the `async` attribute would enable that?

Answer (score 0):

All I could figure out is using e.g. `window.fetch()` (needs polyfill for older browsers) for pre-fetching the content:

```
window.fetch('//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js')
.then(function(res) { return res.status;})
.then(function(status) {
  if (status === 200) {
    console.log('ready');
  }
});
```